# How do I assign, and loop, the tr number as id using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, loops

I want to calculate the table rows, and then assign to each `<tr>` in the `<table>` an id number based on the number of that row within the `<table>`.

I did the calculation like this:

```
var currentIndex = $('table tbody tr').length
```

and I got the number of rows; then, when I tried to loop through the rows, it changed the id in all the rows to the same id.

For example, I need to make it so that, for row number 1 the `id` is `1`, for row 2 the `id` is `2`, etc.

```
function generateId() {

    for (i = 0; i < $('table tbody tr').length; i++) {
        console.log('Hello World', + i -1);
        $('table  tbody tr td :input').attr('id', + i).attr('name', + i).prop('class', 'form-control form-control-sm form-control-solid formInput-' + i);
        //$('table tbody tr td :input').attr('name', + i);
        //$('#table tbody tr td :input').attr('class', 'form-control form-control-sm form-control-solid' + i);
    }
```

any ideas ??!!

Comment: How do you build this table? From a query/DB?

Comment: jquery, i do the following, add a new tr via jquery, and each time i need to assain a dynamic id, and i need the id is serialized, even if i deleted a row, i'll make as a function to calculate the rows, and assign the id after the delete or add. i hope i was clear :)

Comment: @TariqJaziri I have updated the code the answer. Try that

Comment: You forgot to add the HTML of your `<table>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give **id to each row** based on number of rows. You can do it like this:-

```js
const rows = $('table tbody tr');
for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
   let row = $(rows)[i];
   let input = $(row).children('td').children('input');
   $(row).attr('id', i+1);
   $(input).attr('id', i+1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>02</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: i need another thing please, i have inputs in the each td in the tr, i need to  assign the  same id of the tr to all of the inputs under the tr, how could i make it too ?

Comment: @TariqJaziri We can give id to input field also. But remember that, Id should be unique in the page. Its a good practice. So, if you want to give same id to multiple events, then don't use id, instead use same class. You can use same class for multiple elements

Comment: sure, i know it has to be unique, i'll add some reference before the row number to explain each element,  could you kindly update the code to let me know how to assign the id number to the input !

Comment: @TariqJaziri Oky I will update it.

Comment: @TariqJaziri I have updated the code based on your requirement. Try that

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$('table  tbody tr td :input').attr("id",function() {
  return "idprefix"+$('table  tbody tr td :input').index($(this));
});
```

Also it's not recommended that id is a number.

**Demo**

```js
$('table  tbody tr td :input').attr("id",function() {
  return "idprefix"+$('table  tbody tr td :input').index($(this));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```